# How to sign the hash of a message using EIP712?

Tags: signature, 0x

There are many guides and online services on how to sign a message using eip712. But they all apply to messages.

Now, if I already have the hash of my message, how to use MetaMask without other third party JavaScript library or Python in order to get the signature of `0x6c211393193b1eb91fbbe20e9a080e5ad36cff4a06b37871d9672cbf15bd304a` ?

Comment: I just wanted to use the 0x exchange, not to write code for signing stuff for creating a zrx order…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply cannot.

I think you messed up a few concepts.

1. Metamask is just a container of private keys. You don't need metamask to sign a message, but you need a private key.
2. Metamask is designed to interact with dapps, which will automatically trigger metamask's signing GUI for you to click, but there is no such feature to sign a raw message.
3. If you want to sign a message (no matter if it hashed or not), you will need some code. At least some commands.
4. EIP-712 is for signing a structured object. Metamask does not do any EIP-712 signing.